# Root space inner products and the partial order on roots

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

For a root system $R$ and a choice of positive roots $R^+$ it is a standard fact (see, e.g., Bourbaki, "Lie Groups and Lie Algebras," Theorem 1 of Section 1.3 of Chapter VI) that

1. if $(\alpha,\beta) > 0$ then $\alpha - \beta \in R$, for any $\alpha\neq \beta \in R$,
2. if $(\alpha,\beta) < 0$ then $\alpha + \beta \in R$, for any $\alpha\neq-\beta \in R$.

The standard partial order $\geq$ on $R^+$ is given by $\alpha \geq \beta$ if $\alpha - \beta \in Q^+$ the non-negative integer span of the simple roots $\Pi$.

From 1 it is clear that if  $(\alpha,\beta) > 0$ for $\alpha,\beta\in R^+$ then either $\alpha \geq \beta$ or $\alpha \leq \beta$. What happens for the case $(\alpha,\beta) < 0$? Is it always true that, as in the $A$-series,  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are incomparable? When $(\alpha,\beta) = 0$, is there some smart way to distinguish those that are comparable from those that are not?

Comment: Nice question! Small correction: I believe you want to define $\geq$ not on all of $R$ but on $R^+$, right?

Comment: In $G_2$, $(\alpha, \beta) < 0$ doesn't imply incomparability. Let $\gamma$ be the short simple root, and $\delta$ the long simple root. Then $(\gamma, \gamma+\delta) <0$ and $\gamma < \gamma+\delta$.

Comment: Also not true in $D_4$: Writing $\gamma_0$ for the central simple root and $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$, $\gamma_3$ for the other simple roots, $(\gamma_0, \gamma_0+\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3) < 0$.

Comment: @SamHopkins: I am probably making an obvious mistake, but why would I restrict to $R^+$. The question makes sense for all $R$ doesn't it?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: Nice counter example! Do you have any idea about the zero pairing case?

Comment: What is usually called the "root poset" of the root system is the set of *positive roots* $R^+$ with the partial order you defined. Your question does not make much sense if we consider all of $R$ because for example, if $\alpha$ is a simple root, then certainly $(\alpha,-\alpha) < 0$ but $-\alpha \leq \alpha$.

Comment: Yes, of course! Thanks for the clarification. I will edit the question.